# Making members of a node list content editable?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, nodelist

I have been working on a piece of code that involves toggling contenteditable on and off for an unordered list with the push of a button. So far I have been accessing the unordered list itself, and toggling content editable. But the problem is that this makes it so list items can be created and deleted, which I do not want. And I cant manually change the content editable of each item individually, because the amount of list items will change based on another button.

Recently I have been fiddling around with node lists to access all of the lists children, specifically using:

`var list = document.querySelector(".days").childNodes;`

Which gives me a node list with all of the items within the list (days is the class of the unordered list). However, I can't seem to figure out how to toggle content editable for each list item. I know you can access members of the node list like an array, but checking if a member is contenteditable or changing its contenteditable does not work.

```
function myfunction()
    {
      var list = document.querySelector(".days").childNodes;
     
        if(list[1].contentEditable == "false")
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                list[i].contentEditable = true;
            }
        }
   }
```

The javascript stops working immediately after creating the variable list.

Is there some sort of notation I'm missing or am I misunderstanding how nodes work? Is there a better way to change the contenteditable of all the children of an unordered list?

Comment: Why are you using only second element in list[1].contentEditable == "false"?

Answer (score 1):

The issue that a nodeList is not a true array. You can’t really treat it like an array. It doesn’t have the array methods. You have to convert a nodeList into an true JS Array.

When I work with nodeList I create a method that I use to do this whenever I do a querySelectorAll.

```
nodeListToArray( selected ) {
    return [].slice.call( selected );
};
```

And I use it as such.

```
NodeListToArray( querySelectorAll('a') );
```

That will give you an array collection of all the selected items.

I your case. You would do this.

```
var list = nodeListToArray( document.querySelector(".days"));

list.forEach( day => {
  day.contentEditable = !day.contentEditable;
});
```